# store the json file that contains private key

Tags: java, google-api

I am trying to access Google play developer API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/ to build an inapp purchase subscriptions for my company Application.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bundle it into the application. Instead, store it in an application specific directory like `~/.MyApp` with any filename of your choice, for instance `epocratesserviceaccount.json`.

For better security, it might be a good idea to set unix file attributes to restrict access to current user only:

```
chmod 400 ~/.MyApp/epocratesserviceaccount.json
```

Note that many user secrets are stored this way - for instance your ssh private key.

Comment: I didnt get by what you meant. "Do not bundle it into the application, store it in an application specific directory". What is the difference between the two things you mentioned ?

Comment: "bundle in application" means, it is part of the application jar; while creating a directory is outside the jar (=not bundled).

Comment: So you are saying it should not be part of the codebase in repository and that it should be part of the server outside the JAR file?

Comment: yes, the authorization key should never be in git (or any other VCS), and it should also not be stored inside your deliverable artifact (jar, tar, zip, whatever). Instead, you should instruct the user how to obtain it, and where to place it, so that the application can work with it.